# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contains' of undefined

Tags: javascript, getattribute

Hi i like to loop trough all "slide" items that contains a class active and take their "data-headertext" attribute. What am i doing wrong?

```
<div class="slide active"></div>

    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('slide');

    for (var i = 0, len = elems.length; i < len; i++) {                
        if (elems.classList.contains("active")) {
          myJavascriptFunc
          }
        }

       function myJavascriptFunc() {
         alert(this.getAttribute('data-headertext'));
       }
```

Comment: elems is a collection, not a single element.... You are looping over it, but you are not referencing the single element. `elems[i]` And your `myJavascriptFunc` is not going to work with "this", the `this` is going to be `window`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`elems` in your code is a Node list which doesnot have property `classList`. You should access `classList` of element inside  `elems`

```
if (elems[i].classList.contains("active"))
```

**Simpler Way:**

And also can do that using [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) giving it multiple classes and loop using [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```
const elems = document.querySelectorAll('.slide.active')
elems.forEach(a => console.log(a.getAttribute('data-headertext')))
```

In this case you want to get the `data` attributes. So better to use [`HTMLElement.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)
`

```
const elems = document.querySelectorAll('.slide.active')
elems.forEach(a => console.log(a.dataset.headertext));
```

Comment: But how to get a data attribute only from "active" element and not from all?

Comment: @Wojciech You mean that there is only one `active element` inside whole document?

Comment: Yes, only one active.

Comment: @Wojciech Then use `querySelector('.active').dataset.headertext`